# Unable to set number value in Jira custom field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to modify the value of a custom field in Jira.

I do it through the following Curl:

```
curl -D- -u 'x:y' -X PUT --data '{"fields":{"customfield_67":{"value":18.20}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://host/jira/rest/api/2/issue/PRUEBAS-315
```

I have also tried to modify the type of quotation marks: simple, double, without them,...

Modifying strings I don't have problems, but I do trying to modify this when it is a number. Even though I am sending a number, it tells me that it is not. I have followed the documentation:

[Jira REST API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/)

Code:  400

> Response:  {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_67":"Operation value must be a number."}}

/jira/rest/api/2/issue/test-2/editmeta:

```
  "customfield_67":{  
     "required":false,
     "schema":{  
        "type":"number",
        "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
        "customId":182
     },
     "name":"Unit Tests Coverage",
     "operations":[  
        "set"
     ]
  },
```

Jira version 7.6.0

Comment: Which response you recieve? Behavior like you describe  usually happens when you don’t have field at edit screen.

Comment: Thank you @sintasy, post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution went through skipping a level. I understand that the strings I use are in a combo box, while this is not. That's how it works:

```
curl -D- -u 'x:y' -X PUT --data '{"fields":{"customfield_67":18.20}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://host/jira/rest/api/2/issue/PRUEBAS-315
```

I didn't find anything in the Jira API documentation, although it's probably specified somewhere.

Comment: There https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/ is examples about edit requests for any types of standart customfields by the way.